# template specialization for wchar_t

Tags: c++, templates, unicode

Can somebody explain why this doesn't work?

```
template < typename T > struct tester { static const size_t value = 0; };
template <> struct tester< char > { static const size_t value = 1; };
template <> struct tester< unsigned short > { static const size_t value = 2; };

size_t nTest = tester< wchar_t >::value;
```

On my compiler, `wchar_t` is typedef'd as `unsigned short`. Why is the default template being used when the underlying type has a specialization?

Edit: OK, So I was wrong about it being type defined. Intellisense was showing me something else. My cross platform, and surrogate, question remains though.

This has thrown me a curveball because I want to work with `wchar_t` depending on it's size.

Another related question. How can I work with `wchar_t` in a cross platform manner? I know it's 16 bits on windows, and elsewhere it can be 32 bits. If it's defined as a 32 bit type does that mean it doesn't (as in compiler forced) use surrogate pairs?

Would something like this work?

```
template < typename T, size_t N = sizeof( wchar_t ) > struct remap;
template <> struct remap< wchar_t, 2 > { typedef unsigned short type; };
template <> struct remap< wchar_t, 4 > { typedef unsigned long type; };
```

Comment: Perhaps you're mistaken and your compiler works correctly (so `wchar_t`  is an independent type instead of a typedef)? Try adding a specialization for `wchar_t` and see if it doesn't get used (it certainly does with the compilers I have handy).

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @JerryCoffin a specialization for `wchar_t` does get used, but in the given example, it doesn't. I've also tried type defining my own types and they all work, but that wchar_t doesn't. How can I check if it's an independant type or not? and would this effect cross platform usage?

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm trying to specialize for wchar_t depending on it's size.

Comment: @Waldermort: Apparently (as I suggested above) your compiler works correctly -- it defines `wchar_t` as its own type, *not* a typedef for `unsigned short` (even though it may have the same representation as `unsigned short`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin edited my above comment. How can I check that? Using VS2010, placing curser on the type it shows, at top of IDE, it being a typedef.

Comment: @Waldermort: I'm not sure what you're seeing, but I know for certain that VS has implemented `wchar_t` as a real type for a while now (I'm sure back to at least VS 2008, and I *believe* a while before that).

Comment: @JerryCoffin, hmm, maybe it's not reading a header file correctly or something. So specializing for both `wchar_t` and `unsigned short` should work, on windows at least. My cross platform questions still remained unanswered though.

Comment: @Waldermort VC has a compiler option (turned on by default) that treats `wchar_t` as a distinct type. If you disable that, it gets typedef'd to `unsigned short`. Maybe Intellisense is screwing up and showing you that typedef. Your test above proves that it is being treated as a distinct type. If you want to know the number of bits in a `wchar_t`, use `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(wchar_t)`.

Comment: @Praetorian: ...or `std::numeric_limits<wchar_t>::digits`.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for that. Seen a few macros in various header files that intellisense shows to be not in use, relating to `wchar_t`, I always thought it was simply defined.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Or that; I don't like that one very much cause it messes with the number for signed types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard specifies that `wchar_t` is a unique type and not a typedef. On some non-conforming implementations, or with some implementation-defined option, it may be a typedef, but you cannot rely on this or rely on it being typedef'd to any particular type in portable code.

Yes, your `remap` specializations will work; `remap<wchar_t>::type` will be `unsigned long` on platforms with a four byte `wchar_t` and `unsigned short` on platforms with a two byte `wchar_t`. Of course `wchar_t` is not limited to those two sizes, and a two byte value doesn't mean it's 16 bits, etc. If you want to write portable code based on the largest value `wchar_t` can hold you might look at `WCHAR_MAX` or one of the options shown in the comments, rather than `sizeof(wchar_t)`.

> If it's defined as a 32 bit type does that mean it doesn't (as in compiler forced) use surrogate pairs?

The standard doesn't actually specify `wchar_t` in a way that's particularly useful for the things people usually want to use it for. The intent of `wchar_t` is to provide a type where any character in the current locale will be represented as a single `wchar_t` value, in order to enable easier text processing. As such `wchar_t` 1) isn't required to use the same encoding in all locales and 2) surrogate pairs aren't really permitted.

Windows' use of UTF-16 sort of gets around that seconds point by not supporting any locale that contain characters that require surrogate pairs. Which means that portable code won't deal with surrogate pairs on any platform, including Windows.

But yes, on platforms with 32 bit wide `wchar_t` UTF-32 is a common `wchar_t` encoding for many locales, especially if you stick to locales that use UTF-8 as the `char` encoding.

Comment: Windows most definitely does return and accept surrogate pairs when necessary. It may not normalize them in any consistent way, but it can "handle" them.

Comment: @rubenvb If you're responding to "portable code won't deal with surrogate pairs," that did not mean that surrogates aren't used on Windows.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can pass strings with surrogate pairs to WinAPI functions, and get them if you ask for stuff like filenames containing them. And how are you going to handle Unix' use of UTF-8 throughout its API functions without converting all over the place?

Comment: @rubenvb WinAPI code is not portable. Functions like `std::fopen` cannot handle Windows filenames that use surrogate pairs. I'm not sure I understand your third issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your template to the following, you don't need to specialize it:

```
template < typename T > struct tester { static const size_t value = sizeof(T) / 8; };
```

On platforms where `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 2, UTF-16 is used, so surrogates apply.

On platforms where `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 4, UTF-32 is used, so surrogates do not apply.